# Convert a PNG with 4 bands to any format with 1 band and a color table

Tags: imagemagick, png, bmp, gdal

I have a PNG with 4 bands but I want only 1 band with a colour table. I tried saving it as a 256-color-bitmap in MS Paint and it worked.

But I need to do it automatically. I tried ImageMagick: `convert E8.png E8256.bmp` but it did not work.

So this is the original picture:

**ImageMagick `identify`:**

```
E8.png PNG 8250x4090 8250x4090+0+0 8-bit sRGB 231KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

**gdalinfo:**

```
Driver: PNG/Portable Network Graphics
Files: E8.png
Size is 8250, 4090
Coordinate System is `'
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0, 4090.0)
Upper Right ( 8250.0,    0.0)
Lower Right ( 8250.0, 4090.0)
Center      ( 4125.0, 2045.0)
Band 1 Block=8250x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA
Band 2 Block=8250x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA
Band 3 Block=8250x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA
Band 4 Block=8250x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Alpha
```

I want to have a picture with one band and a color table so I opened E8.png with MS Paint and saved it as 256-color-bitmap. The result:

**ImageMagick `identify`:**

```
E8256.bmp BMP3 8250x4090 8250x4090+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 33.75MB 0.265u 0:00.138
```

**gdalinfo:**

```
Driver: BMP/MS Windows Device Independent Bitmap
Files: E8256.bmp
Size is 8250, 4090
Coordinate System is `'
Origin = (-1890.000000000000000,1890.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (3780.000000000000000,-3780.000000000000000)
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (   -1890.000,    1890.000)
Lower Left  (   -1890.000,-15458310.000)
Upper Right (31183110.000,    1890.000)
Lower Right (31183110.000,-15458310.000)
Center      (15590610.000,-7728210.000)
Band 1 Block=8250x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Palette
  Color Table (RGB with 256 entries)
    0: 0,0,0,255
    1: 128,0,0,255
    ...
    255: 255,255,255,255
```

But when I try `convert E8.png E8imagemagick.bmp` I get:

**ImageMagick `identify`:**

```
 E8imagemagick.bmp BMP 8250x4090 8250x4090+0+0 8-bit sRGB 135MB 0.406u 0:00.409
```

**gdalinfo:**

```
Driver: BMP/MS Windows Device Independent Bitmap
Files: E8imagemagick.bmp
Size is 8250, 4090
Coordinate System is `'
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0, 4090.0)
Upper Right ( 8250.0,    0.0)
Lower Right ( 8250.0, 4090.0)
Center      ( 4125.0, 2045.0)
Band 1 Block=8250x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
Band 2 Block=8250x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
Band 3 Block=8250x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
```

---

**Edit:** Here([uploaded.net](http://uploaded.net/file/qjbfwtpj) -- [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rmqh9g48dyyvq74/E8.png?dl=0)) is the original PNG and here ([uploaded.net](http://uploaded.net/file/xkg4poq2) -- [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bnfftu69wv7blu1/E8256.bmp?dl=0)) the BMP I obtained using MS Paint.

Comment: Hard to say without your image but try ImageMagick `convert input.png -separate -type palette out%d.bmp`

Comment: thx I added the 2 images at the end of the question.

Comment: What is that awful link to malware-infested rubbish?

Comment: uhm its just a png and a bmp at uploaded.net ? I also added dropbox links. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: Is what ImageMagick calls a "band" not usually called "channel" in, uh, pretty much about all other image processing software?

Comment: you mean what gdalinfo calls "band". I don't know about all the other image processing software but imagemagick calls it channel. And gdal is a collection of GIS-tools so you could be right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this command:

```
 convert E8.png -colors 256 E8-256colors.bmp
```

gets you closer to what you want? It is a bit large, though, this bitmap... (129 MByte). So this one should be smaller:

```
 convert E8.png -type palette -colors 256 E8-palette-256colors.bmp
```

The last one is only 16 MByte.

You headline says 'any format', so PNG may be in order too? It creates much smaller output:

```
 convert E8.png -type palette -colors 256 E8-palette-256colors.png
```

(The size now is only 122 kByte.)

Your original image consists of 6 colors only, and so does your new output:

```
 identify -format "%f: %k\\n" E8.png E8-palette-256colors.png
   E8.png: 6
   E8-palette-256colors.png: 6
```

Or

```
 identify E8.png E8-palette-256colors.png
   E8.png PNG 8250x4090 8250x4090+0+0 8-bit sRGB 231KB 0.000u 0:00.000
   E8-palette-256colors.png[1] PNG 8250x4090 8250x4090+0+0 8-bit sRGB 6c 125KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

Comment: thanks, you saved the day! The first one didn't work, it had 3 bands again but the 2nd and 3rd are fine and I use the third one :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want exactly...

```
convert E8256.bmp -separate -type palette PNG8:out%d.png
```

Comment: You say you have a 4-band PNG, yet the image you have shared is a 3-band BMP?